# ES6 constructor returns instance of base class?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor, ecmascript-6, derived-class

The constructor of a derived class returns an instance of the base class.

The following code explains my problem:

```
// Vector is defined by an external module (Unreal.js)
class TestB extends Vector {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    Log() {
        console.log("" + this);
    }
}
console.log(new TestB() instanceof TestB) // returns false !!! why ??? 
console.log(new TestB() instanceof Vector) // returns true...

class TestA extends Array {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
    Log() {
        console.log("" + this);
    }
}
console.log(new TestA() instanceof TestA); // returns true, all is good
```

How is this possible?

Comment: `console.log(new TestB() instanceof TestB)` returns true for me

Comment: Yes, it only occurs in my project, with this `Vector` object. I want to know what makes this object underivable.

Comment: Show us the Vector class

Comment: I don't know how it's defined, it's from Unreal.js

Comment: Also cannot reproduce. You need to show us the definition of the Vector class.

Comment: https://github.com/ncsoft/Unreal.js/ is this Unreal you mean?

Comment: `Vector` may not be defined for extension. It may be intended for use as a normal function rather than constructor, possibly returning an object rather than setting up an instance.

Comment: Do not think so. Even if it was a normal function it would work.

Comment: @SHilch If the function returns any object, `new` will use that object and discard the instance it created.

Comment: In what environment are you executing your ES6 code? Are you transpiling it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It would appear that `Vector` is implemented in a way that makes it incompatible with `class`.

Here's an example of one way `Vector` could do that:

```
function Vector() {
  var v = Object.create(Vector.prototype);
  return v;
}

class TestB extends Vector {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}

console.log(new TestB() instanceof TestB);  // false
console.log(new TestB() instanceof Vector); // true
```

The key here is that since `Vector` returns a different object than the one `new` created, it's of the wrong type. A relatively little-known thing about constructor functions is that if they return a non-`null` object reference, the result of `new Constructor` is the object the constructor returned, rather than the object `new` created.

Here's a snippet for those whose browsers support `class`:

```js
function Vector() {
  var v = Object.create(Vector.prototype);
  return v;
}

class TestB extends Vector {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}

console.log(new TestB() instanceof TestB); // false
console.log(new TestB() instanceof Vector); // true
```

...and a [live copy on Babel's REPL](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015&code=function%20Vector()%20%7B%0A%20%20var%20v%20%3D%20Object.create(Vector.prototype)%3B%0A%20%20return%20v%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20TestB%20extends%20Vector%20%7B%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aconsole.log(new%20TestB()%20instanceof%20TestB)%3B%20%20%2F%2F%20false%0Aconsole.log(new%20TestB()%20instanceof%20Vector)%3B%20%2F%2F%20true) for those whose browsers don't.

To my surprise, both Babel and Chrome let me do this using `class Vector` as well and returning a value from `constructor`; I haven't figured out (yet) from the specification whether it's actually valid:

```js
class Vector {
  constructor() {
    var v = Object.create(Vector.prototype);
    return v;
  }
}

class TestB extends Vector {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}

console.log(new TestB() instanceof TestB); // false
console.log(new TestB() instanceof Vector); // true
```

To get around it, you'll likely need to use a per-instance hack, like copying all of `TestB.prototype`'s methods onto the instance. Ideally, rather than hacking, try to use `Vector` via aggregation (aka "composition", e.g., by having a `Vector` instance as a property of your class's instances) rather than inheritance, since it's not set up for inheritance.

Comment: What kind of pattern do you mean by "via aggregation rather than inheritance"? Do you mean extending each instance (or the `Vector` prototype itself) with additional properties? (Good answer, I've just never heard "aggregation" used in this context.)

Comment: @apsillers: The other term for it is "composition," e.g., having a `Vector` instance as a property, rather than inheriting it.

Comment: Aha, so using a "has-a" relationship, rather than an "is-a" relationship.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the exact cause of this problem, but hacking **proto** solves the issue. :)

```
class TestB extends Vector {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.__proto__ = TestB.prototype;
    }
    Log() {
        console.log("" + this);
    }
}
```